# gstreamer won't play rtsp

Tags: gstreamer, ubuntu-16.04

I have this gstreamer command that plays stream from one Ubuntu 16.04 box but two others.

As far as I know I have same packages installed regarding gstreamer on all boxes because I ran sudo apt-get install gstreamer1-0* so that all gstreamer 1.0 packages are installed. I find it strange that it does not work on other

Following commands where used:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://<user>:<password>@<IP>/axis-media/media.amp user-id=root user-pw=xxxxxxxxxxc latency=150 ! decodebin max-size-time=30000000000 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

or

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=rtsp://<user>:<password>@<IP>/axis-media/media.amp
```

This will open a stream of a Axis camera with h264. I don't understand why it does not work on two Ubuntu 16.04 boxes but works on one. All of these are the same Ubuntu 16.04 with same gstreamer packages installed.

Could there maybe be another package except gstreamer that is necessary in order for gstreamer to stream rtsp?

The error a get when it is not playing

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'autovideosink0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayX11\)\ gldisplayx11-0";
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://root:pass@172.26.134.166/axis-media/media.amp

(gst-launch-1.0:4036): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: Ignoring invalid ignore_hosts value '*]'
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Could not open resource for reading and writing.
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(6795): gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:
Failed to connect. (Generic error)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Found the command from this webpage:

http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/gstreamer-client-pipeline-to-view-video-from-AXIS-M1054-Network-Camera-td4667092.html

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems that it was the proxy that caused the issue. When I disabled proxy I was able to stream with gstreamer on all boxes.

Best regards